# Is it safe to use a HDMI connection from PC to TV?

Tags: hdmi

Is there a known possible technical vulnerability?
Which kind of data could leak?
Is it even possible?

(I use a so called "smart TV")

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

Security is always a matter of probabilities. There do not currently appear to be any known vulnerabilities between a TV connected to a PC via HDMI. This does not mean there aren't any vulnerabilities, only that they are not currently known. This connection is generally considered "safe".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can!

Do it myself with the first gen. Unibody MacBook Pro to a TV.

Data does flow upstream from the TV ('sink device' in engineering-speak) back to the PC ('source device') is the signalling which specifies what audio & video formats the TV can handle and that the TV is enabled to receive DRM'd data. There are more trivial signalling going on which you can read about at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI .

I don't believe there is a significant risk of hackage.

However, [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management#Television) in almost all broadcast, cablecast, and streamed content prevents recording, by a 'smart' TV or other devices.

Answer (score -1):

It is perfectly safe. Other than negotiating some information on how to display data, no information is sent to the TV. Other than the video being displayed. The TV has no access to your PC via HDMI.

Comment: I would personally use the phrase "It is considered safe" rather than the emphatic "It is perfectly safe". There are not currently any known vulnerabilities, but that does not mean they don't exist.

Comment: HDMI can carry USB data back and forth, and USB hacks have been demonstrated for Macs and Windows.  In addition, smart TVs are rarely updated (firmware or OS), so attackers can easily look up vulnerabilities and make use of them.